# Qt Designer's preview ui is not the same when it running in python

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside2

This is the preview

[image]

This is how it looks when it running in python

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt handles various styles that are enabled depending on various flags such as environment variables, and Qt Designer probably uses some styles by default, so the style shown by the preview may be different from the application when it is run.

Analyzing the style it seems to me that Qt Designer uses the "fusion" style, so the solution is to add:

```
app.setStyle("fusion")
```

---

If you want to visualize your design with other styles from Qt Designer you must execute: Form-> Preview in -> style

---

If you want to know all the styles available in your installation you can run the following:

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

print(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.keys())
```

In my case I get the following:

```
['Breeze', 'bb10dark', 'bb10bright', 'cleanlooks', 'gtk2', 'cde', 'motif', 'plastique', 'Oxygen', 'Windows', 'Fusion']
```

Comment: my code is "app = QApplication([])", so I need to add a new line "app.setStyle("fusion")", is that right?

Comment: You solved my problem I really appreciate that, and is there have any more styles because I only found three styles in Preview option.

Comment: @Aiden Yes, you have to compile the plugins of each style (many depend on the OS, in the case of Linux there are many available) but there is a drawback: you have to have Qt installed and manually compile the plugins that for a beginner is usually a pain head.

Comment: I hate compiling.If I want more style, is installing Qt on linux a good idea?

Comment: @Aiden No, I have had to compile many styles. But you can create your own style, check: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-styles-example.html